# How do I change the color of a hovered item?

Tags: javascript, css

I'm currently trying to implement kind of a dark mode and I'm struggling with this:

[Navbar when dark mode is **disabled**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZZEEN.jpg)

[Navbar when dark mode is **enabled**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MSTHu.jpg)

As you can see, when dark mode is disabled .nav-item is hovered and text can be seen, but when dark mode is enabled, it's almost impossible to see due to the color.

[This is how I'm toggling class to enable and disable dark mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b9llr.jpg)

Thing is I can't put this:

`.nav-item:not(.is-active):hover`

as a className in order to toggle between **.nav-item:not(.is-active):hover** with a specific color for light mode and **.nav-item:not(.is-active):hover** with a different color (let's say white) for dark mode.

I hope you can help me. Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you toggle the `dark-mode` class on for `nav-item`, you can use the `.dark-mode.nav-item:not(.is-active):hover` CSS selector. Creating a style using this selector will allow you to target `nav-item`s with the `dark-mode` class. In that style you can define a different color for hover while in dark mode.

For more info about what kind of CSS selectors are available, check [this page from W3 schools](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp).